# How to get local heroku app to connect to remote REDIS?

Tags: node.js, heroku, redis

I am new to Heroku/Redis. I have created a basic node.js and express APP to which I have added a REDIS addon.

```
heroku addons:create heroku-redis:hobby-dev -a MyApp
```

I have an `index.js` from which the server runs on port 5000

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000
const client = require('redis').createClient(process.env.REDIS_URL);

express()
  .use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
  .set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))
  .set('view engine', 'ejs')
  .get('/', (req, res) => res.render('pages/index'))
  .listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on ${ PORT }`))
```

My repo is connected to my personal github from Heroku where the app runs fine, but whenever I try to run it locally it seems it tries to connect to REDIS locally so I have the following error when running my node command (node index.js):

```
Listening on 5000
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
```

I am very new to this but am presuming that the environment is wrong: `process.env.REDIS_URL`, how can I connect straight to the Heroku cloud instead of my local one?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Copy Heroku config vars to your local .env file

   ```
   heroku config -s > .env
   ```
2. Run your app locally using the Heroku Local command

   ```
   heroku local
   ```

   When you start your app using `heroku local`, the .env file is read, and each name/value pair is inserted into the environment, to mimic the action of config vars.

Details at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-local

Comment: I am unable to find an .env do I need to create one? And if so, where do I put it?

Comment: Hey! The command above seems to create one (sorry I am very new to this) so I take it from there that I should ignore the following warnings in terminal `heroku local
[WARN] Cannot read property '1' of null
[OKAY] package.json file found - trying 'npm start'
[OKAY] Loaded ENV .env File as KEY=VALUE Format
[WARN] Cannot read property '1' of null
[OKAY] package.json file found - trying 'npm start'`

Comment: If I try to run `node index.js` as per package.json it does not work, so I take it I will have to run `heroku local` every time

Comment: @HGB, correct, you should use `heroku local` instead of `node ...`, it will inject vars from `.env` file into the node's `process` for you

Answer (score -1):

var client = redis.createClient(port, hostname);

Comment: Can you please show an example of how to use the client var?